# Ruby strings with embedded variables

Tags: ruby, yaml

How can I store ruby string with embedded variables in yaml, but insert variable values only when I get string from yaml?

Comment: what do you mean by string with embedded variables? Are you sure you want to insert variable *names* only ...

Comment: He wants to do interpolation later. I guess.

Comment: I read the question as wanting to do something like "Text for Yaml #{variable}".to_yaml where the variable is not evaluated before it is sent to yaml.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
str = "Hi %{name}, %{msg}. Bye %{name}." #yaml it, de-yaml it back to string
h = {:name=> "John", :msg=> "this message is for you"}
puts str % h
#=>Hi John, This message is for you. Bye John.
```

Answer (score 2):

Embed erb in yaml file as rails did:

```
# config/initializers/load_config.rb
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env]


# config/app_config.yml
development:
  key1: <%= # ruby code ... %>
test:
  key1: <%= # ruby code ... %>
production:
  key1: <%= # ruby code ... %>
```