# Use placeholders in YAML

Tags: yaml, placeholder, computed-properties, indirection, template-variables

Is there a way to use placeholders in YAML like this:

```
foo: &FOO
    <<propname>>: 
        type: number 
        default: <<default>>

bar:
    - *FOO 
       propname: "some_prop"
       default: "some default"
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905103/yaml-reusable-variables-with-case-specific-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

### Context

- YAML version 1.2
- user wishes to

  - include variable placeholders in YAML
  - have placeholders replaced with computed values, upon `yaml.load`
  - be able to use placeholders for both YAML mapping keys and values

### Problem

- YAML does not natively support variable placeholders.
- Anchors and Aliases almost provide the desired functionality, but these do not work as variable placeholders that can be inserted into arbitrary regions throughout the YAML text. They must be placed as separate YAML nodes.
- There are some add-on libraries that support arbitrary variable placeholders, but they are not part of the native YAML specification.

### Example

Consider the following example YAML. It is well-formed YAML syntax, however it uses (non-standard) curly-brace placeholders with embedded expressions.

The embedded expressions do not produce the desired result in YAML, because they are not part of the native YAML specification. Nevertheless, they are used in this example only to help illustrate what is available with standard YAML and what is not.

```yaml
part01_customer_info:
  cust_fname:   "Homer"
  cust_lname:   "Himpson"
  cust_motto:   "I love donuts!"
  cust_email:   homer@himpson.org

part01_government_info:
  govt_sales_taxrate: 1.15

part01_purchase_info:
  prch_unit_label:    "Bacon-Wrapped Fancy Glazed Donut"
  prch_unit_price:    3.00
  prch_unit_quant:    7
  prch_product_cost:  "{{prch_unit_price * prch_unit_quant}}"
  prch_total_cost:    "{{prch_product_cost * govt_sales_taxrate}}"   

part02_shipping_info:
  cust_fname:   "{{cust_fname}}"
  cust_lname:   "{{cust_lname}}"
  ship_city:    Houston
  ship_state:   Hexas    

part03_email_info:
  cust_email:     "{{cust_email}}"
  mail_subject:   Thanks for your DoughNutz order!
  mail_notes: |
    We want the mail_greeting to have all the expected values
    with filled-in placeholders (and not curly-braces).
  mail_greeting: |
    Greetings {{cust_fname}} {{cust_lname}}!
    
    We love your motto "{{cust_motto}}" and we agree with you!
    
    Your total purchase price is {{prch_total_cost}}
```

### Explanation

- Below is an inline image that illustrates the example with colored regions in green, yellow and red.
- The substitutions marked in *GREEN* are readily available in standard YAML, using anchors, aliases, and [merge keys](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html).
- The substitutions marked in *YELLOW* are technically available in standard YAML, but not without a [custom type declaration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+custom+data+types), or some other binding mechanism.
- The substitutions marked in *RED* are not available in standard YAML. Yet there are workarounds and alternatives; such as through [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) or string template engines (such as python's `str.format`).

[image: Image explaining the different types of variable substitution in YAML]

### Details

Templates with variable placeholders is a frequently-requested YAML feature.

Routinely, developers want to cross-reference content in the same YAML file or [transcluded](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/include/info) YAML file(s).

YAML supports anchors and aliases, but this feature does not support arbitrary placement of placeholders and expressions anywhere in the YAML text. They only work with YAML nodes.

YAML also supports [custom type declaration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+custom+data+types)s, however these are less common, and there are security implications if you accept YAML content from potentially untrusted sources.

#### YAML addon libraries

There are YAML extension libraries, but these are not part of the native YAML spec.

- Ansible

  - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html
  - (supports many extensions to YAML, however it is an Orchestration tool, which is overkill if you just want YAML)
- https://github.com/kblomqvist/yasha
- https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/yamlp

### Workarounds

- Use YAML in conjunction with a template system, such as Jinja2 or Twig
- Use a YAML extension library
- Use `sprintf` or `str.format` style functionality from the hosting language

### Alternatives

- [YTT YAML Templating](https://developer.ibm.com/blogs/yaml-templating-tool-to-simplify-complex-configuration-management/) essentially a fork of YAML with additional features that may be closer to the goal specified in the OP.
- [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org) shares some similarity with YAML, but with additional features that may be closer to the goal specified in the OP.

### See also

#### Here at SO

- [YAML variables in config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404633/reading-yaml-config-file-in-python-and-using-variables)
- [Load YAML nested with Jinja2 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967064)
- [String interpolation in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777987/string-interpolation-in-yaml)
- [how to reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)
- [Use YAML with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150782/use-yaml-with-variables)
- [How can I include a YAML file inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-an-yaml-file-inside-another?rq=1)
- [Passing variables inside rails internationalization yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055753/passing-variables-inside-rails-internationalization-yml-file)
- [Can one YAML object refer to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141438/can-one-yaml-object-refer-to-another)
- [is there a way to reference a constant in a yaml with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169121/is-there-a-way-to-reference-a-constant-in-a-yaml-with-rails)
- [YAML with nested Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967064/load-yaml-nested-with-jinja2-in-python)
- [YAML merge keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168718/yaml-merge-level/47203224#47203224)
- [YAML merge keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48196167/42223)

#### Outside SO

- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
- https://github.com/dreftymac/awesome-yaml#variables
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+variables+in+config+file&t=h_&ia=web

Comment: Great answer, very detailed and explained, thanks! Unfortunately, the ones marked in green are not available to Jekyll users, at least not on Jekyll v3.8.5. I tested myself.

Comment: What works on Jekyll is `&hello` (alias) and `*hello` (anchor), as explained here: https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_yaml_tutorial#example-6-variables

Answer (score 10):

With [Yglu](https://yglu.io) Structural Templating, your example can be written:

```
foo: !()
  !? $.propname: 
     type: number 
     default: !? $.default
    
bar:
  !apply .foo: 
    propname: "some_prop"
    default: "some default"
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of Yglu.

Comment: I wanted to like Yglu, but I had better luck with konverter. Not as pure since it uses jinja, but I couldn't quite get my head around Yglu

Answer (score 4):

I suppose https://get-ytt.io/ would be an acceptable solution to your problem

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to achieve templating in `yaml` files as well and I found [dreftymac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/8243326) really helpful as a starting point. After researching and coding for few hours this is my answer, please let me know if/how I can improve this.

I am not doing anything too special, I try to leverage python's string templating syntax and abuse the string format method a little. So it's all python's string templating and substitution that is doing the magic here. I have modified the way [dreftymac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/8243326) templated his `yaml` file to use as an example.

#### YAML:

```yaml
part01_customer_info:
  cust_fname: "Homer"
  cust_lname: "Himpson"
  cust_motto: "I love donuts!"
  cust_email: homer@himpson.org

part01_government_info:
  govt_sales_taxrate: 1.15

part01_purchase_info:
  prch_unit_label: "Bacon-Wrapped Fancy Glazed Donut"
  prch_unit_price: 3.00
  prch_unit_quant: 7
  prch_product_cost: "eval!#{part01_purchase_info[prch_unit_price]} * {part01_purchase_info[prch_unit_quant]}"
  prch_total_cost: "eval!#{part01_purchase_info[prch_product_cost]} * {part01_government_info[govt_sales_taxrate]}"

part02_shipping_info:
  cust_fname: "{part01_customer_info[cust_fname]}"
  cust_lname: "{part01_customer_info[cust_lname]}"
  ship_city: Houston
  ship_state: Hexas

part03_email_info:
  cust_email: "{part01_customer_info[cust_email]}"
  mail_subject: Thanks for your DoughNutz order!
  mail_notes: |
    We want the mail_greeting to have all the expected values
    with filled-in placeholders (and not curly-braces).
  mail_greeting: |
    Greetings {part01_customer_info[cust_fname]} {part01_customer_info[cust_lname]}!

    We love your motto "{part01_customer_info[cust_motto]}" and we agree with you!

    Your total purchase price is {part01_purchase_info[prch_total_cost]}
```

> I have changed `{{}}` to `{}` and added `eval!#` which is an identifier

#### Python:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import yaml

EVAL_IDENTIFIER = "eval!#"


def eval_math_expr(val):
    if val.startswith(EVAL_IDENTIFIER):
        val = val.replace(EVAL_IDENTIFIER, "")
        val = eval(val)
    return val


def str_template_substitute(full, val=None, initial=True):
    val = val or full if initial else val
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for k, v in val.items():
            val[k] = str_template_substitute(full, v, False)
    elif isinstance(val, list):
        for idx, i in enumerate(val):
            val[idx] = str_template_substitute(full, i, False)
    elif isinstance(val, str):
        # NOTE:
        # Templating shouldn't be confused or tasked with extra work.
        # I am attaching evaluation to string substitution here,
        # just to prove this can be done.
        val = eval_math_expr(val.format(**full))
    return val


data = yaml.load(open('./data.yml'))
str_template_substitute(data)

pprint(data)
```

> **Note: This function is pretty powerful as this can work on dictionaries which is what JSON/YAML and many other formats convert to in python.**