# YAML 1.2 anchors not working in js-yaml 3.10.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

When loading [YAML anchors](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)  in node.js (v4.8.7) using the [js-yaml 3.10.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) package (there's a nice example of using it [here](http://thisdavej.com/getting-started-with-yaml-in-node-js-using-js-yaml/)) I get the following error:

> "cannot merge mappings; the provided source object is unacceptable"

For instance in my input yaml file I have something like the following as my anchor:

```
defaultEd: &defaultEd
  - 'Pennsylvania College of Technology AS'
  - 'Pennsylvania College of Technology BS'
```

And where the anchor is referenced in my input yaml file I have the following:

```
...
education:
  <<: *defaultEd
qs:
  - 'Reading'
  - 'Writing'
...
```

I'm hoping to accomplish the following in my output:

```
education:
  - 'Pennsylvania College of Technology AS'
  - 'Pennsylvania College of Technology BS'
```

The error is displayed something like this:

```
{ [YAMLException: cannot merge mappings; the provided source object is unacceptable at line 21, column 1:
    qs:
    ^]
  name: 'YAMLException',
  reason: 'cannot merge mappings; the provided source object is unacceptable',
  mark: 
   Mark {
     name: null,
     buffer: 'defaultEd: &defaultEd\n  - \'Pennsylvania College of Technology AS\'\n  - \'Pennsylvania College of Technology BS..
 <<: *defaultEd\nqs:\n  - \'Reading\'\n  - \'Writing\'\n  - \'Rithmatick\'\nexperience:\n  - {posName: \'Database Analyst / Net Tech\', companyName: \'Choices People Supporting People\'}\n\u0000',
     position: 435,
     line: 20,
     column: 0 },
  message: 'cannot merge mappings; the provided source object is unacceptable at line 21, column 1:\n    qs:\n    ^' }
Error View file does not exist: someTest.yml
```

Comment: In this case there's no need to merge mappings. You can just use `education: *defaultEd`. I guess js-yaml forbids merge when there is nothing to merge.

Comment: Actually, I just saw, that the anchor `defaultEd` isn't a mapping. so there is no way to merge it. Can you specify what kind of data you expect to be in `education`? Probably my suggestion to use `education: *defaultEd` is still the right one.

Comment: @tinita Yeah that did it, thank you.  I wasn't aware of what a mapping is, but I'm guessing that a mapping has something to do with it being a layered object of some sort?

Comment: @tinita You can add an answer if you want, I'll select it as the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably misunderstood / mixed up the usage of aliases and the merge key `<<`.

Any node in YAML can have an anchor attached:

```
---
mapping: &map
  a: 1
  b: 2
sequence: &seq
  - a
  - b
scalar: &scalar foo
mapping-alias: *map
sequence-alias: *seq
scalar-alias: *scalar
```

The merge key `<<`, which is not part of the YAML spec itself, is supported by some processors. It lets you merge an aliased mapping into another mapping.

```
defaults: &defaults
  a: 1
  b: 2
# .....
some-mapping:
  <<: *defaults
  c: 3
```

See http://yaml.org/type/merge.html

A mapping in YAML is usually called a dictionary, associative-array, hash or sometimes object (Javascript) in programming languages.

In your case, you probably just want:

```
education: *defaultEd
```