# Yaml translation starting with placeholder

Tags: yaml, translation, placeholder, symfony4

I'm trying to translate with a variable placeholder and it's working fine, except when the translation string begins with the placeholder.

E.g.

```
example.translation: %variable% example translation
```

If there is any non white space character before the first %, it's ok. Else it says the yaml file is invalid.

Comment: **See also:** [Use placeholders in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the percent sign probably could be allowed a the start of plain scalars that are not starting at the beginning of a document (where they indicate a directive), not all parsers allow this. You can check that online  by comparing the [`Nim` based parser](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) with the [PyYAML based one](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=example.translation%3A%20%25variable%25%20example%20translation&type=json). The YAML specification explicitly disallows `%` (which is a [c-indicator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-indicator)) from appearing at the beginning of a [plain scalar](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-plain-first(c)).

You would run into similar problems if your edit would introduce colons (followed by whitespace) or backslashes.

The simple solution is quoting that value:

```
example.translation: '%variable% example translation'
```

I use single quotes here, as within those only single quotes have special meaning (if your original has a single quote, make that two single quotes).

Quoting YAML scalars with double quotes is also possible, but then any backlashes (`\`) and double quotes in the original must be preceded by a backslash (i.e. `\\` and `\"`)

You can also make such a plain scalar into a literal style block-scalar:

```
example.translation: |-
  %variable% example translation
```

You'll **have to** use the `-` chomping indicator, otherwise your scalar ends in a newline, where the original did not. Then you don't have to
do anything special for single or double quotes in your original, nor for any backslashes.