# In YAML, is there any way to use variables inside a literal block scalar?

Tags: yaml

I'd like to use a variable inside a YAML literal block scalar.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
markup: |
  <title>
    {{ title }}
  </title>
```

Can that be done somehow?

I appreciate that this example would be trivial to execute without using a literal block scalar, but my actual use case inside a Foundation 6 stack would contain more markup and more variables than what I'm showing here.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a variable inside a literal block scalar.

First of all there are no variables in YAML (the word *variable*, occurs only once in the YAML specification, in an example document, nr. 2.28).
And second, this is called **literal** for a reason. No interpretation is done of any of the characters.

Of course it is possible that some program that loads your document does something with the text between curly braces (`{}`). E.g interprets it as a jinja2 template. But without knowing what such a program does or expects, it is equally valid to expect something like that for the information between angle brackets (`<>`).

Therefore **within YAML** there is **no way** to use variables, neither inside of literal block-style scalars, nor outside them.

---

As for the templating: I have worked with program that generated YAML from a template and applied templates on the loaded string scalars (by recursively walking the tree). Your example could be either.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.  I'm new to Yaml and I'm only experiencing it in connection with Panini, Foundation's templating system integrated with Handlebars. I see that I merged concepts from one into capabilities that I wished to use within Yaml.  Thank you for setting me straight.