# How to reuse an environment variable in a YAML file?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, yaml

I'm trying to reuse an Environment variable in a YAML file. 
The problem is that I need to use the value of the Environment variable if exists or a default value. But this default value varies in different places of the configuration.

For instance, I can do this:

```
urls:
 url1: ${BASE_URL:http://1}
 url2: ${BASE_URL:http://2}
```

...
And so on.

But what I want to do is:

```
urls:
 base: ${BASE_URL}
 url1: ${urls.base:http://1}
 url2: ${urls.base:http://2}
```

The problem is that in the latter approach if the Environment variable is not set then property **urls.base** will have this string "${BASE_URL}" as value so the default values will not be used

If I set a default empty value to the **urls.base** property then url1 and url2 will be empty and no default values will be used.

Other reasons other than reusing the environment variable are:

- Better name
- Execute logic if the variable exists and does not have an empty value

**PD:** I'm using Spring boot

Comment: There is no such functionaltiy in YAML, `${BASE_URL}` is just a normal scalar. Any functionality to replace that with or without some default value comes from the program **before or after loading the YAML document**.

Comment: **See also:** [Use placeholders in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/42223)