# Accessing environment variables in a YAML file for Ruby project (using ${ENVVAR} syntax)

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am building an open source project using Ruby for testing HTTP services: https://github.com/Comcast/http-blackbox-test-tool

I want to be able to reference environment variables in my `test-plan.yaml` file. I could use ERB, however I don't want to support embedding any random Ruby code and ERB syntax is odd for non-rubyists, I just want to access environment variables using the commonly used Unix style `${ENV_VAR}` syntax.

e.g.

```
order-lunch-app-health:
  request:
    url: ${ORDER_APP_URL}
    headers: 
      content-type: 'application/text'
    method: get
  expectedResponse:
    statusCode: 200
    maxRetryCount: 5
```

All examples I have found for Ruby use ERB. Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to deal with this? I an open to using another tool to preprocess the YAML and then send that to the Ruby application.

Comment: See my updated answer - now also with what I believe is a better alternative, without going through Ruby's `%{var}` substitution.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 2):

I believe something like this should work under most circumstances:

```
require 'yaml'

def load_yaml(file)
  content = File.read file
  content.gsub! /\${([^}]+)}/ do
    ENV[$1]
  end

  YAML.load content
end

p load_yaml 'sample.yml'
```

As opposed to my original answer, this is both simpler and handles undefined ENV variables well.

Try with this YAML:

```
# sample.yml
path: ${PATH}
home: ${HOME}
error: ${NO_SUCH_VAR}
```

#### Original Answer (left here for reference)

There are several ways to do it. If you want to allow your users to use the `${VAR}` syntax, then perhaps one way would be to first convert these variables to Ruby string substitution format `%{VAR}` and then evaluate all environment variables together.

Here is a rough proof of concept:

```
require 'yaml'

# Transform environments to a hash of { symbol: value }
env_hash = ENV.to_h.transform_keys(&:to_sym)

# Load the file and convert ${ANYTHING} to %{ANYTHING}
content = File.read 'sample.yml'
content.gsub! /\${([^}]+)}/, "%{\\1}"

# Use Ruby string substitution to replace %{VARS}
content %= env_hash

# Done
yaml = YAML.load content
p yaml
```

Use it with this `sample.yml` for instance:

```
# sample.yml
path: ${PATH}
home: ${HOME}
```

There are many ways this can be improved upon of course.

Comment: do you mean `file` instead of `sample.yml` in the load_yaml function?

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing is easy, and I recommend you use a YAML loaderd/dumper
based solution, as the replacement might require quotes around the
replacement scalar. (E.g. you substitute the string `true`, if that
were not quoted, the resulting YAML would be read as a boolean).

Assuming your "source" is in `input.yaml` and your env. variable 
`ORDER_APP_URL` set to `https://some.site/and/url`. And the following
script in `expand.py`:

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

def substenv(d, env):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, str) and '${' in v:
                d[k] = v.replace('${', '{').format(**env)
            else:
                substenv(v, env)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(d):
            if isinstance(v, str) and '${' in v:
                d[idx] = item.replace('${', '{').format(**env)
            else:
                substenv(item, env)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(Path(sys.argv[1]))

substenv(data, os.environ)
yaml.dump(data, Path(sys.argv[2]))
```

You can then do:

```
python expand.py input.yaml output.yaml
```

which writes `output.yaml`:

```
order-lunch-app-health:
  request:
    url: https://some.site/and/url
    headers:
      content-type: 'application/text'
    method: get
  expectedResponse:
    statusCode: 200
    maxRetryCount: 5
```

Please note that the spurious quotes around 'application/text' are preserved, as would be any comments
in the original file.

Quotes around the substituted URL are not necessary, but the would have been added if they were.

The `substenv` routine recursively traverses the loaded data, and substitutes even if the substitution is in mid-scalar, and if there are more than substitution in one scalar. You can "tighten" the test:

```
        if isinstance(v, str) and '${' in v:
```

if that would match too many strings loaded from YAML.