# is it possible to simplify the pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart

with the libraries and assets my pubspec.yaml file is quite large, it is possible to split the file and perform an import.

Example:

```
flutter:
  
  fonts:
    - family: JosefinSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/JosefinSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/JosefinSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/JosefinSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

into something like:

```
flutter:
  fonts: 
-var
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use placeholders in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml)