# Variable in Resuable component in OpenAPI

Tags: openapi

Say I have a reusable component:

```
  parameters:
    ResourceName:
      in: path
      name: name
      description: The name of the Resource (See tag for resource)
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
```

I have a use for this component across several endpoints, and the identifier that I see for these endpoints is the tag. Can I insert the tag name in the description as its inserted?

An example implementation in an operation

```
        tags:
         - SampleResourceName
        parameters:
         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/ResourceName'
```

How can I insert `SampleResourceName` in the description of the parameter, IE:

```
  parameters:
    ResourceName:
      in: path
      name: name
      description: The name of the {tag}
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI and YAML do not support variable placeholders.

But you can write a script that would parse your OpenAPI file and process it the way you need. Check out [Use placeholders in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41620674/113116) which contains links to YAML extension libraries that can help you with this.