# YAML - Assign single value to multiple keys

Tags: variables, configuration, yaml, substitution

I have a YAML configuration file and there are multiple keys that need to be assigned with the same value, so I was trying to figure out a way to do so but nothing seems to be working.

Below is my YAML configuration:

```
maskingSchema:
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_GET":
    fields:
      - username
      - email
    defaultPattern: "*****"
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_CREATE":
    fields:
      - username
      - email
    defaultPattern: "*****"
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_UPDATE":
    fields:
      - username
      - email
    defaultPattern: "*****"
```

As we see, multiple keys have repetitive values, so I want a way to define a variable with the value and use it on multiple keys are at once.

I tried to extract a variable in the following manner.

```
myValue:
  fields:
    - username
    - email
```

And use it like:

```
maskingSchema:
  [ROOT_RESOURCE_GET,ROOT_RESOURCE_CREATE,ROOT_RESOURCE_UPDATE]: ${myValue}
```

This is a valid YAML syntax, but it doesn't get resolved at runtime.

I also tried the following:
Declared the variable in the following manner:

```
myValue: &myVar
  fields:
    - username
    - email
```

And used it like:

```
maskingSchema:
  [ROOT_RESOURCE_GET,ROOT_RESOURCE_CREATE,ROOT_RESOURCE_UPDATE]: *myVar
```

However, this doesn't work either.
I've tried a few other methods but nothing seems to work.
I'm lost at this point, would appreciate some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use placeholders in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

YAML is not a programming language and does not have variables.

However, it is able to name a subgraph via an anchor and later reference that subgraph with an alias. It looks like this:

```yaml
maskingSchema:
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_GET": &config
    fields:
      - username
      - email
    defaultPattern: "*****"
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_CREATE": *config
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_UPDATE": *config
```

If `defaultPattern` differs, you'll need to do

```yaml
maskingSchema:
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_GET":
    fields: &config
      - username
      - email
    defaultPattern: "*****"
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_CREATE":
    fields: *config
    defaultPattern: "*****"
  "ROOT_RESOURCE_UPDATE":
    fields: *config
    defaultPattern: "*****"
```

If you want to do anything more sophisticated, you'll need to use some kind of templating engine which is what most YAML power users (Ansible, Helm, SaltStack, …) do.